# SQLite: ¿Cómo eliminar fisicamente todos los datos de una tabla?

Tags: sqlite, tablas

Estoy usando el siguiente código para borrar las tablas de mi base de datos.

```
"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableName;"
```

Las tablas se borran pero me he dado cuenta de que los datos siguen dentro del archivo. Es decir, después de ejecutar este comando esperaría que mi archivo tuvirera cero bytes, y sin embargo el archivo no pierde ni un solo byte de su tamaño.

¿Hay alguna forma de borrar la tabla y también todos los datos de esa tabla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La eliminación de una tabla, como ya te has dado cuenta, es simplemente una eliminación lógica, la estructura y los datos, siguen estando físicamente en la base de datos, el espacio usado se va recuperando a medida que se necesite. Para eliminar y reorganizar el archivo fisico del una base `sqlite` tienes la clausula [`VACCUM`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html). La ejecución de este comando, reorganiza el espacio de la base de datos al mínimo indispensable, reduciendo el espacio y la fragmentación de los datos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su respuesta!!